# Axios POST request fails with error status code 500: Internal Server error

Tags: javascript, post, flask, axios, internal-server-error

I'm trying to send a POST request locally with a username and password in the body through Axios.

I'm deploying a Flask app on http://127.0.0.1:5000/login, which handles the /login route. The POST request fails with the following error

```js
POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/login 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
```

I researched a bit and thought it might be a problem with CORS, but this doesn't seem to be the case because I tried an Axios GET request and it worked fine (response logged properly). Here's part of my code

```js
axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000").then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/login", {
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password
      }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
```

Looking at Chrome DevTools, I can see that the POST request payload is properly populated. I then tried printing out the keys server-side in the Flask app using the following code, but I got nothing, empty. (which was expected since the POST request failed)

```js
dict = request.form
    for key in dict:
        print('form key '+dict[key])
```

HOWEVER using Postman with the corresponding keys and values works properly and returns a response and prints out the keys (see above). Where is the failure coming from? Why would the POST request fail when a GET seems to work just fine?

Comment: I had same problem. I had syntax error in my back end code. check your request by postman and make sure your server side code runs true.

Comment: @MiladYousefi, great thanks. I made the request from POSTMAN and found on the backend that my "PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large" hence got the 500 internal error.

Answer (score 68):

Feb 2021. Wasted 2 hours on this. Not much help on this famous library on internet.

**Solution:**

- In the catch block, the `error` which will always be `500 internal server error`
- so, use `error.response.data` instead of `error`.

**Code:**

```
try {
  let result = await axios.post(          // any call like get
    "http://localhost:3001/user",         // your URL
    {                                     // data if post, put
      some: "data",
    }
  );
  console.log(result.response.data);
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error.response.data);     // NOTE - use "error.response.data` (not "error")
}
```

---

**Update:**

I ended up writing a common function for handing error:

File: common.app.js

```
export const errorUtils = {
  getError: (error) => {
    let e = error;
    if (error.response) {
      e = error.response.data;                   // data, status, headers
      if (error.response.data && error.response.data.error) {
        e = error.response.data.error;           // my app specific keys override
      }
    } else if (error.message) {
      e = error.message;
    } else {
      e = "Unknown error occured";
    }
    return e;
  },
};
```

More info: https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors

Comment: still valid thanks!. spent all morning trying to solve this! Once i checked error correctly i found a solution in 5 mins.

Comment: True, happy to know it helped.

Comment: So it seems it throws an error when the response code is 500. This seems like a good thing to make optional.

Comment: holy moly! you probably also saved me two hours!!! When you `console.log(error)`, you just see the `error.stack` string... the object is an `instanceof Error`.. but is NOT just an `Error` with a `stack` and `message`. Even if I pass to `console.dir` or `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error)))`... This `error.response` json just doesn't appear! On top of that.. these crazy objects are being thrown, so typescript can't get you TS types.

Comment: happy to know it helped :)

Answer (score 11):

So I also got stuck in the same problem and the solution that I found was something like this :

```
let data = JSON.stringify({
  username: this.state.username,
  password: password
});

const response = axios.post(url,data,{headers:{"Content-Type" : "application/json"}});
```

This solution worked for me.

Comment: axios stringifies bodies and uses that header by default, does it not?

Answer (score 5):

Apparently Axios didn't take kindly to the raw JSON object

```
{username: this.state.username, password: password}
```

but passing the data into a FormData object seemed to work just fine!

Answer (score 3):

After working 2 hours, I realized I made a mistake about the body and data. So, in the axios make sure you pass the data like this.

```
async function loadToken(){
  try{
    response = await axios({
      url: ``, 
      headers: {
        'Authorization': '',
        'Content-Type': '',
      },
      data: '',
      method: 'POST'
    });
    let data = response.data;
    return {
      tokenInfo:data,
      timestamp:new Date().getTime()
    }
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("err->", err.response.data)
    return res.status(500).send({ret_code: ReturnCodes.SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG});
  } 
}
```

My previous code pass the data like this, which is wrong

```
async function refreshToken(){
  try{
      let headers = {
        authorization: '',
        'Content-Type': ''
      }
      let url =  ``
      let body = {
        grant_type: '',
        refresh_token: global.tokenInfo.refresh_token
      }
      data = await axios.post(url, body, {headers});
      let data = response.data
      console.log(data)
      return {
        tokenInfo:data,
        timestamp:new Date().getTime()
      }
  } catch(err) {
      console.log("err->", err.response)
      return res.status(500).send({ret_code: ReturnCodes.SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG});
  }
}
```

Simply try my first code, hope that solves your issue.

Comment: Check this link to find how to write a good answer on Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time it happens because of using **wrong content type header**.

Open postman and see "Body" tab. There you can find the content type of your post data. It's also accessible from "Headers" tab. There should be a `Content-Type` header. The correct format of `data` you send through a POST request depends on `Content-Type` header. for example, json content type requires a json (javascript object) data or form-data content type requires a FormData.

To set a header in axios, change the code like this:

```js
axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/login", {
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password
      }, {
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
      }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error i had the JSON capital and it should have been lowercase

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found I had to tell Axios that 500 errors are valid. I did this by passing the `validateStatus` parameter to the Axios request.

Example:

```
  return axios
    .get(url, {
      params: flattenedParams,
      validateStatus: (status: number): boolean => { return status >= 200 }
    })
    .then((response: AxiosResponse) => {
      if (response.status == 500) {
        throw new Error("server side error");
      }
      return response;
    });
```